# Move one PS4 hard disk to another

Tags: ps4, hard-drive

Is it possible to remove the hard disk from a PS4 and insert it into another and continue using all the saved games and data as if it was in the original PS4?

Comment: I can not tell you how to, as I have Xbox. However; a warning: You can **always** remove the hard drive. Unless it is a method **expressly permitted** by Sony, doing so will void your Warranty. Easiest rule: If you have to break a seal, or take out a screw, its probably not worth it.

Comment: @Timelord64: https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5107/~/upgrade-ps4-hdd

Comment: As you can see from the link you found, the PS4 has a removable harddrive. The hard drive is console specific, that is, it is designed soley to operate with the PS4 console. With a bit of tech savy, you could easily use it to "case" a differant harddrive, and use that. But again, this will void warranty.

I would recommend following that page. Use it to answer your own question - reference the page, but try to provide a good guide from it here. Other people will run into this problem, and a well written guide will likely attract a fair few upvotes.

Comment: @Timelord64: Sony officially supports upgrading the PS4s hard disk. It does not void the warranty. Any regular 2.5 inch SATA hard drive will work. There is no need for a special drive. My question was whether moving a hard disk from one PS4 to another will work not whether the hard disk can be upgraded.

Comment: fair enough. Given that, I can not possibly see why it wouldn't. It seems Sony have gone a lot further to ensure you can easily swap drives around. To put in a system that prevents you from recovering a hard drive from, say, a broken console seems a bit unlikely.

Comment: @Timelord64 Sony always supported upgrading hard drives. The PS3 even had an extra slot for the hard drive so you wouldn't have to open the console and break the warranty seal when you changed it. However, I think you couldn't just swap drives to another console, because the console was "activated" to the PSN account, so it recognized the hardware, but I'm not sure exactly. Here is a similar problem: http://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2fu80g/can_an_older_ps4_hdd_be_swapped_into_a_new_ps4/ Seems like you can't just move the PS4 hard drive into another console. Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: @Kodama looks like it isn't possible from the link you sent. You should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

A hard drive used on one PS4 cannot be used on another PS4 unless you format the drive first. This is a security measure put in place to prevent data from being used on anything other than the original console.

The hard drive itself can be used on another console, but you won't be able to use the data or games stored on it. It will need to be reset / formatted.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? I feel like it's kinda weird that you wouldn't be able to... Seeing as how your PS4 could crap out on you, and this would prevent you from moving anything over to a new one...

Comment: I don't have a source for this, but this is the way PS3 handles it too. And I've tried this my self on a PS3. The reason for this restriction is that each console generates keys for DRM that's is specific to the console and hard drive, so people don't sell the hard drives and effectively give away games.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes more sense.